# How to fetch JSON data to Prototype Cell in 2 Columns

Tags: ios, json, swift, fetch

I'm developing app for ios with swift. I'm stuck something which is i couldn't fetch the data from json to prototype cell properly. I created 2 different label which is should be fetch json main categories. Instead of fetch by one by it's just repeat itself. Also i couldn't fetch the images too. I'll share the images and my codes to you. Thank you for you help. 
Here is the how i can parse from json

```
func startParsing(data :NSData)
    {
        let dict: NSDictionary!=(try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary

        for var i = 0 ; i < (dict.valueForKey("PAPATYA") as! NSArray).count ; i++
        {
            arrDict.addObject((dict.valueForKey("PAPATYA") as! NSArray) .objectAtIndex(i))
        }
        for var i = 0 ; i < (dict.valueForKey("BURCU") as! NSArray).count ; i++
        {
            arrDict.addObject((dict.valueForKey("BURCU") as! NSArray) .objectAtIndex(i))
        }
        for var i = 0 ; i < (dict.valueForKey("DENEME") as! NSArray).count ; i++
        {
            arrDict.addObject((dict.valueForKey("DENEME") as! NSArray) .objectAtIndex(i))
        }
        tvJSON .reloadData()
    }
```

after i parse to JSON i'll use this code to bind data to prototype cell

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell : TableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! TableViewCell
        let strTitle : NSString=arrDict[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("URUNADI") as! NSString
        let strfiyat : NSString=arrDict[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("URUNFIYATI") as! NSString
        cell.product_name.text = strfiyat as String
        cell.product_price.text = strTitle as String
        cell.product_name2.text = strTitle as String
        cell.product_price2.text = strfiyat as String

        return cell as TableViewCell
    }
```

[image: Simulator Images]

and here is the Storyboard image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I done that with uıcollection view that's the better way. Thank you